# opam not working on Ubuntu VM

Tags: ubuntu, ocaml, virtual-machine, init, opam

I tried running `sudo opam init` on an Ubuntu virtual box. On pressing `y` after being prompted, the following error occurs:

```
global-config does not define the variable lib
```

Comment: Hi, I am not able to find in the source code of opam (1.3.0) the string 'does not define variable' - which version of opam are you using ? also you do not need to sudo.

Comment: don't use `sudo`, opam is designed to be installed in a user folder, under the user's credentials

Answer (score 0):

Installing Opam 1.2.2 resolved the issue. Thanks for the help.